# Preview last uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm using an old project where I could upload many images but for this one, I only need just one. When uploaded, I should see what's uploaded (preview). When first uploaded, I see the image. If uploaded a different image, I still see the first image. I dont want that, I need to preview the last uploaded image.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.receipt.upload').on('change', function(e) {
  let id = e.target.id;
  let files = e.target.files;
  let image = files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(file) {
    let img = new Image();
    console.log(file);
    img.src = file.target.result;
    $('.'+id).replaceWith(img);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  //console.log(files);
});
```

**Rails html.erb:**

```
<div>
  <%= image_tag('/assets/receipt/missing-receipt.jpg', class: "receipt#{contract.id}") %>
</div>

// Inside a form
<div>
  <%= f.file_field :receipt, id: "receipt#{contract.id}" , class: "receipt upload"%>
</div>
```

Change these makes no difference:

```
let files = e.target.files[0];
let image = files;
```

Comment: It's in a loop so different file upload `id`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created `<img>` `img` does not have `.className` set to `<input type="file">` `.id`. At second `change` event no element exists in `document` with `id` at `jQuery()` call `$('.'+id)`.

Set the `.className` of replacement element `img` to `id`.

```
$('.receipt.upload').on('change', function(e) {
  let id = e.target.id;
  let files = e.target.files;
  let image = files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(file) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.className = id; // set `img` `.className` to `id`
    console.log(file);
    img.src = file.target.result;
    $('.'+id).replaceWith(img);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(image);
});
```

Comment: I was scratching my head on this. My old project was in react. Good one, buddy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the FileReader...

```
$('.receipt.upload').on('change', function(e) {
  let {id, files} = this
  let img = new Image
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0])
  img.className = id
  $('.'+id).replaceWith(img)
})
```

Comment:  I'll try this later and let you know.

Comment: This works but what's actually going on here? Sorry, Im not a js ninja.

Comment: The first line is just [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), using `this` is just an alternativ of `e.target`